# How to keep the ball within the framework of sequential automatic vertical wrap

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.containerMaster {
  border: 2px solid darkgray;
  width: auto;
  height: 310px;
}
.containerSlave {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.ball {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 20px 15px, #7FBBFC, #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="containerMaster">
  <div class="containerSlave">
    <div class="ball">01</div>
    <div class="ball">02</div>
    <div class="ball">03</div>
    <div class="ball">04</div>
    <div class="ball">05</div>
    <div class="ball">06</div>
    <div class="ball">07</div>
    <div class="ball">08</div>
    <div class="ball">09</div>
    <div class="ball">10</div>
    <div class="ball">11</div>
    <div class="ball">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I hope can to this below:

01 11

02 12

03 13

04

05

06

07

08

09

10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/q79ed1ue/

```
.containerSlave {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px; /*item height x 10*/
}
.containerSlave .ball {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Be sure to check out http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Thank you for your answer,Can I ask you more questions

Comment: @MOMO yes, if it's related to the question. but please post a new one if you have another question.